# How can the object be deallocated if this condition is true?

Tags: objective-c

I don't get why if I inspect

```
po [search searchResults]
```

I get: `message sent to deallocated instance 0x8835650`

Even if I'm inspecting the object **after** the following if statement:

```
if ([search searchResults]) {
   NSLog(@"[search searchResults] %@", [search searchResults]); // breakpoint here!
```

I thought the condition is true only if the object searchResults is allocated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is true so long as `search` points to anything other than `nil`.

Even if the instance is deallocated, pointers *to* that instance are not automatically set to `nil`.

**Edit:**

What you have most likely done here is allocated an autoreleased instance of a class, and assigned it to a variable without retaining it; subsequently passing an autorelease pool drain, causing all sorts of headaches.

Comment: Thanks. So, just out of curiosity, how should I change the if statement to effectively check if the instance is allocated ?

Comment: Mostly important, I'm facing difficulties to find when the instance has been assigned without retaining it, given the complexity of the code. Any tip ?

Comment: You can't. It's what is called a stale pointer, and they are, as a rule, a Bad Thing™. You have to find the reason for your pointer going stale, and fix that.

Comment: As for finding the particular spot; the most likely culprit is the place at which `search` is first assigned to.

Comment: solved! finally... I forgot to use self. in front of a property to correctly invoke the setter (and retain the object).